# SAPUI5 Panels - Controlling position of content

Tags: scroll, sapui5, panel, onfocus

I have a number of Panels which, when expanded, show the corresponding questions for that particular 'Category'

The issue I have is, say for example I answer the questions for the 1st panel, the content will scroll down, eventually hiding the panel... fair enough.

However, when I click on the Next Category (Production Area), I need to the page to scroll back up to the first question in the Category, or maybe even just display the selected category at the top of the page.

Is this possible?

Currently, the user has to continually scroll back if when they select the next Category.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is any "ui5-out-of-the-box" solution for your problem, but I guess you can use css-anchors. React to the open-event of the panel and navigate to the corresponding anchor of the panel.

Comment: css anchors sounds good. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @AdamHarkus [inizio's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53187241/5846045) should work fine. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using [`scrollToElement()`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Page/methods/scrollToElement)

```js
var oPage = sap.ui.getCore().byId("pageId"); // you page ID
var oList = sap.ui.getCore().byId("ListId"); // element ID to which it has to scroll
if (oPage && oList) oPage.scrollToElement(oList, 1000);
```

Execute the above code inside the panel event `expand`.

Answer (score 1):

After trying everything, this is what worked for me.

```
onExpand: function (oEvent) {

            if (oEvent.getParameters().expand) {
                var focusID = oEvent.getParameter("id");
                var elmnt = sap.ui.getCore().byId(focusID);
                elmnt.getDomRef().scrollIntoView(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use this control instead which suits your needs

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout

Comment: Wizards and Object pages don't really fit the use-case. It's questions stacked vertically, and expandable rather than steps.